# Proof $(1+i)^t < 1+it$ if $0 < t < 1$

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

I am trying to prove that compound interests grow slower than simple interest in the first year.

I attempted to do this with the following approach.

Let $$f(t) = (1+i)^t$$

then $$f'(t) = \ln({1+i})(1+i)^t$$

while if $$g(t) = 1+it$$

then $$g'(t) = i$$
.

I was able to show that $f(0) = g(0)$ and since we are implicitly assuming that interest $i$ is positive, $i> \ln{1+i}$ shows that simple interest, indeed, starts out growing faster than compound interest.  However, I am having trouble that this ends at $t=1$.

I'm not sure if this is even an efficient approach, but I would really like it if

a), If someone could help me out with the second part.

b), Give an alternative solution that would be easier.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this quite recently? I remember the question because the title was a mess (the title here is my corrected version) and the tags were the same as here and offtopic as here (and I had corrected them too).

Comment: It must have been someone else, because I recently started studying this material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remark that, by a [Taylor expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series),
$$
(1+i)^t = 1+it+\frac{\sigma(\sigma-1)}{2}i^2
$$
for some $\sigma$ between $0$ and $t$. Therefore $\sigma-1<0$, and you conclude.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the third term on the right side?  It looks like the remainder term from the Taylor expansion where $\sigma$ is the number that we know exits that makes the expression equal to each other. In this case, I can see that the last term add something to $1+it$ so it makes it larger than the simple interest, but wouldn't that contradict with the fact that compound interest grows slowly initially?

Comment: The last term is *negative*, since $\sigma<1$.

Comment: That makes so much sense.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Derive on $i$:

$$t(1+i)^{t-1}<t$$
because the exponent is negative.

Comment: Interesting, so you kept $t$ constant and treat the interest rate as the variable.  I can definitely see that working.  Thank you.  Would it be too much to ask if we could deal with the case when $t$ is the variable just for the sake of math?

Comment: Siminore did it.